# javascript formatting

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that seems to have a problem. I've tried JSLint and other tools to see where I might have a missing delimiter.  Eclipse doesn't show me anything either.  In Firebug, the complete block of code shows as disabled line numbers like comment lines do. Anyone know of a good tool?  I used ctrl+K to indent the code I pasted below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.startover').live('click', function() {
            var ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO start over FROM SCRATCH?');
                    if (ReInitAnswer){
                        return true;
         } 
         ELSE {
            alert('canceled');
            return false;
             } 
         });

        $('.notdupe').live('click', function(e) {  
            alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked")); 
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe", 
                data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"), 
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                // show error alert(errorThrown); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 

            $('.alphabet').live('click', function(l) { 
                SelectedLetter = $(l.target).val(); 
                $(".alphabet").each(function(i){
                        var CheckLetter = $(this).val();
                  if (CheckLetter == SelectedLetter){
                    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    $('.NameBeginsWith').val(SelectedLetter);
                  } ELSE {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "");
                  }
            });

    $('.Reinit').attr('value', SelectedLetter); 
    $('.Reinit').trigger ('click');  

    }); 

$(".alphabet").hover(function () {
          var _$this = $(this);
          var usercount = 0;
          $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
          url: "scribble.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json", 
          data: "nbw=" + $(this.target).val(), 
          datatype: "html",
          success: function(res){
             usercount = eval("(" + res + ")").DATA[0][0];
             _$this.append($("<span> (" + usercount +")</span>"));
          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
           console.log('errorThrown');
            } 
        }); 
    }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
      }
    );


        });
```

Comment: One problem is that you can't capitalize `ELSE` and for good reason, too.

Comment: For starters, your "ELSE" declarations should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to tell what you're asking, but if you mean it's formatted wrong, try http://jsbeautifier.org/ for better formatting. Here's that code cleaned up (including the incorrect casing of `else`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.startover').live('click', function() {
        var ReInitAnswer = confirm('Are you sure you want TO start over FROM SCRATCH?');
        if(ReInitAnswer) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert('canceled');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('.notdupe').live('click', function(e) {
        alert("indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"));
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "cfc/basic.cfc?method=SetNotDupe",
            data: "indivNum=" + $(e.target).val() + "&SetValue=" + $(e.target).is(":checked"),
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error alert(errorThrown); 
            }
        });
    });

    $('.alphabet').live('click', function(l) {
        SelectedLetter = $(l.target).val();
        $(".alphabet").each(function (i) {
            var CheckLetter = $(this).val();
            if(CheckLetter == SelectedLetter) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
                $('.NameBeginsWith').val(SelectedLetter);
            } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "");
            }
        });

        $('.Reinit').attr('value', SelectedLetter);
        $('.Reinit').trigger('click');
    });

    $(".alphabet").hover(function() {
        var _$this = $(this);
        var usercount = 0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scribble.cfc?method=CountUsersByLetter&returnformat=json",
            data: "nbw=" + $(this.target).val(),
            datatype: "html",
            success: function(res) {
                usercount = eval("(" + res + ")").DATA[0][0];
                _$this.append($("<span> (" + usercount + ")</span>"));
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('errorThrown');
            }
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems strange that an issue like else/ELSE wouldn't show up as a problem.  Anyway, that did the trick.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive.

`ELSE` must be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

ELSE must be lowercase

```
     ELSE { // <-- this is bad
        alert('canceled');
        return false;
         }
```